# Magento does not recognize the own backend URL and displays 404

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-backend

I have a Magento2 store divided into three docker containers:
Magento2
Maria DB
Nginx

The Nginx receives all queries and forwards them to the Magento2 container. This one processes the incoming request.
But when I try to call [www.mydomain.de/backend-url](http://www.mydomain.de/backend-url), Magento does not recognize that it is the backend URL and displays a 404.
I have already cleared the cache, I have also checked in env.php what is stored, I have also checked the unsecure and secure URL in the database and also checked in the database the redirects. Also, the backend URL was already changed via the Magento CLI and led to no result. When I ask via client which URL is responsible for the backend, it shows me it correctly, but when I enter it in the browser, a 404 is displayed. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

There are few more step you have to verify that is configure or not.

**1. Check Web Server Configuration**

Ensure your Nginx server configuration is correctly set up to handle
requests to the backend URL

```
location /admin {
    proxy_pass http://magento2-container-name;
}
```

**2. Permission Issues**

Ensure that file and directory permissions are set correctly

Answer (score 0):

If error message is :  whoops our bad...
please adjust table core_config_data data  admin/url/custom configurations

If all backend url request is http code 404
need check HttpGetActionInterface and set nginx config

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php last;
}
```